# Jackson polymorphic class with abstract and interface

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

I use spring boot 3.1.2

```
@PostMapping
public void sauvegarderDepot2(@RequestBody DepositPub deposit) {
...
}

public interface DepositPub {
    String getType();
    Long depositId();
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, visible = true, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = DefaultDepositPub.class, name = "default")
})
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public abstract class AbstractDepositPub implements DepositPub{

    public AbstractDepositPub(String type, Long depositId){
        this.type=type;
        this.depositId=depositId;
    }


    private String type;

    private Long depositId;

    public String getType(){
        return type;
    }

    public Long getDepositId(){
        return depositId;
    }


}

@Data
public class DefaultDepositPub extends AbstractDepositPub{

 }
```

When I call controller with this code

```
{
     "@type": "default",
     "depositId": 123
}
```

I get this error

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot
> construct instance of DepositPub (no Creators, like default
> constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to
> concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type
> information